# Makefile- Return value from another target

Tags: docker, makefile, global-variables, return-value

I created two targets in one Makefile.
The generic target `docker-get-label` should read the label value from specific docker container and returns it.
But the var `$(LABEL_VALUE)` in target `testtarget` is empty and prints out nothing.
Inside target `docker-get-label` I can print out the var `LABEL_VALUE`successfully.

Does exist a way to get a value from another target, from the target `docker-get-label`?

```
testtarget:
    $(MAKE) docker-get-label CONTAINER_NAME=xenodochial_maxwell
    echo $(LABEL_VALUE) #empty


docker-get-label:
    $(eval LABEL_VALUE=$(shell docker inspect -f '{{ index .Config.Labels "TESTLABELNAME"}}' $(CONTAINER_NAME)))
```

Comment: This not just "another target".  The `docker-get-label` target is run in _another make instance_ altogether (because you invoked `$(MAKE)` recursively).  No variables defined in a sub-make can be accessed in the parent make, just like no variables you define in one program can be accessed in another program (that's what you're doing: starting a new program).

Comment: Even disregarding the sub-make, the short answer is, it's bad design to try to set a make variable in one target and use it in a different target.  It is almost always a sign of problems to use either the `$(eval ...)` or `$(shell ...)` functions inside a make recipe.  However, you haven't explained what your requirements actually are so we can't really help.

Comment: I  would like to get the value of LABEL_VALUE in target testtarget accessible.

Comment: So, why not just use `LABEL_VALUE=$$(docker inspect -f ....)` in that recipe?  Why put it in a different target?  Or, why not put it as a global variable in the makefile?  Why only set that value inside a specific target?  The answers to these sorts of questions are what I mean by, you haven't really explained the requirements.  Without knowing all the things you need this value for we can't really give you a solution.